# Multiple Case Statement in SQL with aliases

Tags: sql, case, aliases

```
SELECT DISTINCT AppID,
                CASE
                  WHEN Category = '< 18 years old' THEN 'yes'
                  ELSE ''
                END AS '<18years old',
                CASE
                  WHEN Category = 'SSN Exists' THEN 'yes'
                  ELSE ''
                END AS 'Applicant has SSN',
                CASE
                  WHEN Category = 'Self Employed' THEN 'yes'
                  ELSE ''
                END AS 'Self employed'
FROM   Table1
WHERE  AppID = 123
```

***OUTPUT Desired***
I am trying to produce the results below where each AppID has only 1 line with 
all the information pertinent to it.  The code above produces multiple lines 
for each application.  I tried to put the case statements all together with 1 END, 
but I get an error when I use Aliases before the END keyword.  Thanks

```
AppID         <18 Year old           Applicant has SSN           Self employed  

123     yes         yes
124                 yes         yes
125                 yes         yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `group by` rather than a `distinct`:

```
SELECT AppID,
       max(CASE WHEN Category = '< 18 years old' THEN 'yes'
                ELSE ''
           END) AS '<18years old',
       max(CASE WHEN Category) = 'SSN Exists' THEN 'yes'
                ELSE ''
           END) AS 'Applicant has SSN',
       max(CASE WHEN Category = 'Self Employed' THEN 'yes'
                ELSE ''
           END) AS 'Self employed'
FROM   Table1
WHERE  AppID = 123
group by AppId
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Why would I use a MAX function if I do not look for a maximum value ?  Is the MAX function - will help all values appear on the same line ?

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the Case statements as follows and just alias at the end:

```
CASE WHEN 
    Category = '< 18 years old' 
THEN 'yes'
ELSE
    CASE WHEN
        Category = 'SSN Exists'
    THEN 'yes'
    ELSE
        ...
        ...
    END
END AS Alias
```

Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

Your aliases should not be enclosed in ''.

Check on your DB Engine which type of character you must use to enclose aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to do a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  AppID,
        MAX(CASE
          WHEN Category = '< 18 years old' THEN 'yes'
          ELSE ''
        END) AS '<18years old',
        MAX(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'SSN Exists' THEN 'yes'
          ELSE ''
        END) AS 'Applicant has SSN',
        MAX(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'Self Employed' THEN 'yes'
          ELSE ''
        END) AS 'Self employed'
FROM   Table1
WHERE  AppID = 123 
GROUP BY AppID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I also have to count how many occurences in